# Rails: email confirmation RESTful (PUT) URL in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, put, email-confirmation

Rolling my own email confirmation from scratch. Struggling with how to generate the proper routing for my `confirmations_controller`.

new user gets sent an email with link back to app to 'verify' address.

My thought is it should be a PUT action because it WILL make changes to the DB. But, clicking on a link in an email won't submit a 'put' action...or will it? I must be missing something, my own ignorance aside.

```
#config/routes.rb
...
resources :confirmations, only: [:update]
```

`confirmation_url(user.email_token)` generates valid url: `http://localhost:3000/confirmations/ArELEOejYlqbRXdJPavhrp` but when clicking on that link it is received by app as a 'get' request.

How should I be handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What format is your email? If its plain text, it will be a GET. That itself is not a problem for updating the activation page. You could also open a page (with GET) and let them click on a button for final submit (not uncommon).

However, updating through a GET would not bother me for this specific function.

example:

```
# routes.rb
get 'confirmations/:id/confirm' => 'Confirmations#confirm'

# confirmations.rb
class ConfirmationsController < ApplicationController

  def confirm
    # handle the get data here (switch aa flag for the email account)       
   end
end
```

Comment: it is **plain text**. I plan to add HTML as well but there will always a text version (`multi-part `MIME) so I suppose I should be prepared to handle a `GET` request regardless?!?  So, if I was just to break with pure RESTful styling for this how/where would I handle the GET update? In the `edit` action perhaps? but that's clumsy `/confirmations/abcdefghi…/edit`.

Comment: or maybe if they respond to the `HTML` email I handle it with `PUT` in the #update action. otherwise I link to an `/edit` page where they can click on a `PUT` link? or...?

Comment: Added a example. Yes /edit would look a bit weird and you should count with the fact some people don't like html email (so count with plain text).  You can define your own action as-well (see example).  IMO using a GET should not be a issue (in this specific case).

Comment: Great! Thanks. one last question: how best to generate that `confirmations/:id/confirm` url in the mailer? I know there are helpers for RESTful routes; what about these not-so-restful ones?

Comment: As you can see 'rake -T' shows no command path. So you need to create the url by hand. I would write a helper method that renders the url part.  Something like  "http://#{domain}/confirmations/#{token}/confirm" creates the base for the URL. If you email is plain text, then you depending if the email client will nicely render it as a clickable link. If not, the user needs to copy & paste the URL.